# PUZZLE WORLD alphametic

Tags: mathematics, alphametic, missing-digits

[image: Q]

I have  tried to solve this but I can't. Does somebody know the answer?

Ref: Puzzle World, Ed. Nob Yoshigahara and Richard Bozulich, Ishi Press, Summer 1992, Pilot Edition.

Comment: So, we have to fill in the "x"?

Comment: Does each letter (including `x`) represent a different digit?

Comment: x can be same or diffeent digit and this is a question of puzzle and world

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution in which P, U, Z, L, E, W, O, R, and D are all different digits, and leading zeroes are not allowed. I cannot prove it, but I wrote a program to brute force it (it was quite tricky to do it effectively). No solution found with these criteria.

Comment: @QuestionAsker If all the `x` digits in the multiplicand are equal then all the intermediate sum values would all be equal (post-left-shift) too, so all of `W,O,R,L,D` would all be equal to `x` too, but `P,U,Z,L,E,W,O,R,D` are surely meant to be unique digits (otherwise we could just say `0 * 0 = 0`); so it must be that any `x` is free to be any digit (elias suggests it may only be possible if some leading digits are also `0`)

Comment: @elias - unfortunately you must've had a bug.

Answer (score 7):

Since this does not have the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag I have used a computer to

> find the single solution
>  - with `P,U,Z,L,E,W,O,R,D` being unique digits in $[0,9]$, and
>  - all instances of `x` free to be any digit.
>
> That solution is `P,U,Z,L,E,W,O,R,D = 6,9,5,0,3,7,8,2,1`.
>
> Numerically on the left, and with the character `X` for `4` on the right:
>
> ```
>        695503               PUZZLE
>       6684445              PPOXXXZ
>       ------- *            ------- *
>       3477515              EXWWZDZ
>      2782012              RWORLDR
>     2782012              RWORLDR
>    2782012              RWORLDR
>   5564024              ZZPXLRX
>  4173018              XDWELDO
> 4173018              XDWELDO
> ------------- +      ------------- +
> 4649051550835        XPXULZDZZLOEZ
> ```

I did it in a *relatively* similar way to a manual approach

> I haven't made all the inferences I would make manually, but I have reduced the space in steps that would probably be used as part of a manual approach (one would prune more of the space than we need to with a computer, since they calculate so fast):
>
> If one labels the multiplicand `xxxxxxx` as `x6,x5,x4,x3,x2,x1,x0` then the innermost generator (the third function) looks for values of `P,U,Z,Z,L,E` (with unique digits `P,U,Z,L,E`) and `x3` (in $[0,9]$) that produce a valid `x,W,O,R,L,D,x` intermediate sum (with unique digits `P,U,Z,L,E,W,O,R,D`) - there are $242$ such choices.
>
> The generator that wraps around that (the second function) then runs through these choices and looks for values of `x5,x4,x2,x1` that produce intermediate sums with the matching `W,O,L,D` - this yields $2,315$ choices.
>
>  The generator that wraps around that (the first function) then runs through these choices and looks for values of `x6,x0` that produce a final result matching `x,P,x,U,x,Z,x,Z,x,L,x,E,x` - this yields a single result (the two multiplicands as stings).

The Python code:

> ```
> from itertools import combinations, permutations
>
> def iterSolutions():
>     for puzzle, puzzleInt, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 in iterValid_Puzzle_PuzzleInt_X1_X2_X3_X4_X5():
>         p, u, z, z, l, e = puzzle
>         pX = (10 * x1 + 100 * x2 + 1000 * x3 + 10000 * x4 + 100000 * x5)
>         for x6 in range(10):
>             pR = puzzleInt * (1000000 * x6 + pX)
>             for x0 in range(10):
>                 r = str(puzzleInt * x0 + pR)
>                 newP = len(r) > 11 and r[-12] or '0'
>                 if newP == p:
>                     newU = len(r) > 9 and r[-10] or '0'
>                     if newU == u:
>                         newZ = len(r) > 7 and r[-8] or '0'
>                         if newZ == z:
>                             newZ = len(r) > 5 and r[-6] or '0'
>                             if newZ == z:
>                                 newL = len(r) > 3 and r[-4] or '0'
>                                 if newL == l:
>                                     newE = len(r) > 1 and r[-2] or '0'
>                                     if newE == e:
>                                         yield puzzle, ''.join(str(v) for v in (x6, x5, x4, x3, x2, x1, x0))
>
> def iterValid_Puzzle_PuzzleInt_X1_X2_X3_X4_X5():
>     for puzzle, puzzleInt, x3, w, o, d in iterValid_Puzzle_PuzzleInt_X3_W_O_D():
>         for x1 in range(10):
>             s1 = str(puzzleInt * x1)
>             wNew = len(s1) > 5 and s1[-6] or '0'
>             if wNew == w:
>                 for x2 in range(10):
>                     s2 = str(puzzleInt * x2)
>                     oNew = len(s2) > 4 and s2[-5] or '0'
>                     if oNew == o:
>                         l = puzzle[4]
>                         for x4 in range(10):
>                             s4 = str(puzzleInt * x4)
>                             lNew = len(s4) > 2 and s4[-3] or '0'
>                             if lNew == l:
>                                 for x5 in range(10):
>                                     s5 = str(puzzleInt * x5)
>                                     dNew = len(s5) > 1 and s5[-2] or '0'
>                                     if dNew == d:
>                                         yield puzzle, puzzleInt, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
>
> def iterValid_Puzzle_PuzzleInt_X3_W_O_D():
>     for puzzleSelection in combinations('9876543210', 5):
>         for p,u,z,l,e in permutations(puzzleSelection):
>             puzzle = ''.join((p,u,z,z,l,e))
>             puzzleSet = set(puzzle)
>             puzzleInt = int(puzzle)
>             for x3 in range(10):
>                 s3 = str(puzzleInt * x3)
>                 if len(s3) == 5:
>                     w = '0'
>                 elif len(s3) < 5:
>                     continue
>                 else:
>                     w = s3[-6]
>                 d,l,r,o = s3[-2:-6:-1]
>                 if l != puzzle[4]:
>                     continue
>                 if len(puzzleSet | set((w,o,r,d))) == 9:
>                     yield puzzle, puzzleInt, x3, w, o, d
> ```

Running that code (sub-second):

> ```
> >>> for solution in iterSolutions():
> ...     solution
> ...
> ('695503', '6684445')
> >>>
> ```
>
> Which is saying the only solution is `695503 * 6684445`, the multiplication I showed above.

Comment: Great answer! I used a very similar - almost identical approach, but it looks like I've made a bug. Now I have to debug my spaghetti-code...